# How to return superscripted '2' (m2 or ft2) from django to template through render template?

Tags: python, html, django

Sorry for a dumb question but the below,

```
def about(request):
        return render(request, 'blog_app/about.html', {'title': 'm<sup>2</sup>'})
```

shows this output in html,  `m<sup>2</sup>` how to show like this, **m<sup>2</sup>**

Comment: I will use m&sup2; instead, html inside <title> is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template try:

```
{{title|safe}}
```